# Redirect to parent node after saving the field collection item

Tags: entities

There is a field collection field for a content type, it is called `field_item`. I gave a direct link to the users to add content to this field based on the it's parent id. this is the url, `/field-collection/field-item/add/node/$nid`.

After saving the field collection field, the page is redirected to the field collection view page not the parent node and I need to accomplish this.

I tried a few solutions so far but non of them worked.

I tried to do this using rules module, the solution in  [Redirect from a Field Collection to its Parent Node or Entity with Rules](http://dropbucket.org/node/1581) but it didn't work.

I tried this code to test whether altering the form would change the redirect page

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    if($form['#entity_type'] == "field_collection_item" && $form['#bundle'] == "field_item"){
        $form_state['redirect'] = "/user";
        kpr($form_state);
    }
}
```

This code prints the form state

[image]

But after saving the form it still goes to the field collection page.

From what I know field collection is an entity so I tried this to test the redirection

```
function hook_entity_insert($entity, $type) {
   $info = entity_get_info($type);
   list($id) = entity_extract_ids($type, $entity);
   db_insert('example_entity')
       ->fields(array(
        'type' => $type,
        'id' => $id,
        'created' => REQUEST_TIME,
        'updated' => REQUEST_TIME,
        ))
         ->execute();
   drupal_goto("/user");
```

}

But it didn't work again. The admin theme is *seven* but the users theme is something else. I inserted these functions in both *seven* theme's and my custom theme's *template.php*. I also cleared the cache.

How do I can redirect the user to the parent node of the field collection after saving/updating the filed collection?

---

**UPDATE**

The only solution I have found so far is this

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    if($form['#entity_type'] == "field_collection_item" && $form['#bundle'] == "field_item"){
       $form['#submit'][] = "field_collection_item_goto_item";
    }
}

function field_collection_item_goto_item(){
    $url = current_path();
    $array = explode("/", $url);
    drupal_goto("/node/".$array[sizeof($array)-1]);
}
```

Since the node ID of the parent comes at the end of the url, because the url is `/field-collection/field-item/add/node/$nid`so this code works.

But it is preferred to get the host entity nid of the field collection item in the `hook_form_alter` and send this nid to the submit function as a parameter. I did my best but I couldn't find host entity nid so I had to use the url.

Comment: I had this same issue. Updating both field collection and redirect modules fixed it.

Comment: As far as I recall, you don't put a slash in front of the path. Drupal core uses calls like the following: `drupal_goto('admin/config/services/aggregator')`, `drupal_goto("node/$node->nid")`.

Comment: Can you expand on this?  What version were you running before/after?  Is there a particular issue that this is tied to?  Etc.

Comment: Redirect was 7.x-1.0-rc1
Field Collection was .x-1.0-beta8

They are now at
Redirect 7.x-2.x-dev
Field Collection 7.x-1.0-beta11

I have expanded the Basic Page content type to include a field collection of typical fields but if a user clicked the edit link to edit a single instance of the field collection it was creating a redirect. Updating fixed that issue.